# WordPress Custom Post and Page Slug Conflict Issue: Page Not Loading

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I made a custom post on my website and maned it single-blog.php for dynamic individual blog details with slug "example.com/blog/%postname%/" and I also have a dedicated page where I'm showing all the blogs named page-blog.php with slog "example.com/blog/" but when I'm trying to load the page-blog.php page it's not loading but whenever I change the slug of page-blog.php from "blog" to "blogs" it loads perfectly

I'm trying to fix the problem so that both "example.com/blog/%postname%/" and "example.com/blog/" page load properly and without changing the subdirectory "/blog/"

Comment: _"but when I'm trying to load the page-blog.php page it's not loading"_ - `page-blog.php` would apply to a page with the slug `blog`. But it doesn't sound like you actually have one. (And whether you could actually still _create_ one at this point, when your custom post type already uses the `blog/` prefix for its URLs, I don't know, you'd have to test it.)

Comment: thank you for your comment 
I did that but it's not working so I have to create a new page named "page-blogs.php" with slug "/blogs/" and it works fine although it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare your custom post type in the functions.php file, there should be an $arg array (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).

Make sure you have set:

```
    'has_archive' => true,
```

within the array. That should automatically create an "Archive" page which shows your custom posts (if you have an archive.php file), and should show up at example.com/blog/ in your case.

If you want to customise how it looks, your template should be called archive-blog.php, not page-blog.php. That should get automatically picked up too at the /blog URL too.

If you want to be able to take content from a page on the WordPress back-end and put it into your archive-blog.php, that's a little more complex. I do it by:

- Creating a page in the back-end, named "Blog" in your case;
- Taking the page ID, e.g. "8"
- In archive-blog.php, declare $post_id = 8. Then, if you want the title, for example, echo it out by get_the_title($post_id).

Comment: hey BrassMonkey thank you for your reply 
the suggestion you give is this comment it works perfectly and solve my problem thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, Krishnendu! Can you accept it as the correct answer please? (I'm brand new here, and want to build up my reputation, as it's currently on zero! :D )